# Java Webservice: GET returned a response status of 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, jersey-1.0

I got an Webapplication including a webservice. The app is running on a tomcat where an SSL certificate is installed. The application and the webservice is running. If I try to use the webservice through the browser by entering:

https://myapp:8080/myapp/rest/test/hello

I got a working XML, which my webservices produces. Now I wrote an Client application, which is trying to consume this webservice, getting the XML and parsing it. It loads the truststore, get certificate and then establish SSL handshake. Works as designed!

But by trying to start a GET Request to the Webservice, I got an empty Response from it. I tried to log as much as possible and I logged the request which is being made:

> GET https://myapp:8080/myapp/rest/test/hello returned a response status of 401 Unauthorized

Because I dont get any exception, my question is, why is the webservice working, when I use it through the browser but not through code?

Following the code used by my client:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.HTTPSProperties;

import execution_units.SQLTestExecutionUnit;
import execution_units.ScriptTestExecutionUnit;
import execution_units.UnixTestExecutionUnit;

public class WebServiceGET {
/*
 * VARIABLES
 */
// Client
private Client clt_output = null;

// ClientConfig
private ClientConfig cnf_output = null;
private SSLContext ctx_ssl = null;

// ClientResponse
private ClientResponse clr_output = null;

// WebResources
private WebResource wre_output = null;

// Booleans for Connections
private boolean boo_output_connection = false;

// Parsing
private ResponseParsingUnit rpu_parser = null;

// Log
private Logger log = null;

/*
 * CONSTRUCTOR
 */
public WebServiceGET(String str_server_url, String str_host_name, int int_timeout, String str_truststore_path,
        String str_truststore_password, int int_exit_xmlinvalid, int int_exit_notestcases) {

    // Add Class to Log4J framework
    log = Logger.getLogger("wsg");
    log.info("\t\tLog for Web Service GET initialized.");

    // Create SSL Configs
    try {                       
        ctx_ssl = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

        KeyStore truststore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

        truststore.load(new FileInputStream(str_truststore_path), str_truststore_password.toCharArray());

        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");

        tmf.init(truststore);

        ctx_ssl.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());

        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(ctx_ssl.getSocketFactory());

        cnf_output = new DefaultClientConfig();
        cnf_output.getProperties().put(HTTPSProperties.PROPERTY_HTTPS_PROPERTIES,
                new HTTPSProperties(null, ctx_ssl));

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    /* OUTPUT */
    // Create client
    try {

        clt_output = Client.create(cnf_output);

    } catch (Exception x) {
        log.warn("\tInterrupted while cnf_output created client. Exception: ", x);
    }

    // Set timeout (read- and connection- receive the same value.)
    clt_output.setConnectTimeout(int_timeout * 1000);
    clt_output.setReadTimeout(int_timeout * 1000);

    // Tireless Connection Establishment to WebService
    while (!boo_output_connection) {

        // Stitch URL together
        try {                                                       
            log.debug("\tConnection-URL (Output): " + str_server_url);

            wre_output = clt_output.resource(str_server_url);

            // Set MediaType (XML)
            clr_output = wre_output.accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML).get(ClientResponse.class);

            log.debug("\toutput status info (Output): " + "\tSTATUS==>" + clr_output.getStatusInfo()                        
                    + "\tStringResponse==>" + clr_output.toString());

            // following code is not necessary, because the reponse from server is always empty!

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.warn("\tConnection for GET-Request could not be established! Exception: ", ex);
            try {
                log.debug("\tTry to reconnect with server in : " + int_timeout + " [s]");
                Thread.sleep(int_timeout * 1000);
            } catch (Exception ex_sub) {
                log.warn("\tInterrupted while sleeping. Exception: ", ex_sub);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Tried to call your service by deleting browser cookies and cache and check if you get the same response.

Comment: Now I tried what you suggested, same result: Working in browser, not working through code!

Comment: Can you please share the code how you are adding header for authorization?

Comment: I never add a header for authorization manuelly.. All I do is mentioned in the post.